# Community ads for other Slavic languages proposals

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Could the Russian Language be the place to put the **community ads** promoting the proposals for other Slavic languages on Area51? On some sites, like Travel, there are those community ads displayed on the right between hot meta posts and related questions.

The language proposals that are currenty live on Area51 are for [Polish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59729/polish-language) and [Ukrainian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67218/ukrainian-language-and-usage). There was a proposal for Czech language, but it died.

Answer (score 1):

Community ads only work on graduated sites I think, so you can't put any ads on the Russian site, since it's still Beta. :)